# Shrink down empty directories explorer in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for some way to reduce the visible size of directories in the explorer, that only have one directory/file in them. I'm not quite sure how to explain this, but basically I want to turn this:

```
OPEN FOLDER  
-ChildFolder  
--GrandchildFolder  
---GreatgrandchildFolder  
---file  
---file  

Into this:  
OPEN FOLDER  
-ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder  
--GreatgrandchildFolder  
--file  
--file
```

GitHub does something like this, for example on https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/tree/master/src (a java project), you see test/java/org/bukkit (hovering shows "this path skips through empty directories").

Is there any way to do this in VSCode? It's pretty minor but would be really nice to have when working across multiple java projects.

Comment: Not a perfect solution but you could open the GrandchildFolder in VSCode (`Ctrl`+`K`, `Ctrl`+`O`)

Comment: I am looking for same extension for vscode. This feature is in phpStorm and intellij.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should be available mid-december 2019 [with VSCode 1.41](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_41.md#compact-folders-in-explorer).

> ### Compact folders in Explorer
>
> In the File Explorer, we now render single child folders in a compact form.
>   **In such a form, single child folders will be compressed in a combined tree element**.
>   Useful for Java package structures, for example.
>
> Setting **`explorer.compactFolders`** controls this behavior.
>   By default, this setting is turned on.

[image: https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_41/explorer-compact.gif]